# Integrating Visual Studio Test Project with Cruise Control

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I'm looking into using Visual Studio 2008's built in unit test projects instead of NUnit and I was wondering if anyone has any experience in trying to integrate this type of unit test project with Cruise Control.Net.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From some of the initial research it doesn't appear to be a super simple solution.

It appears that doing this involves having Visual Studio 2008 actually installed on the continuous integration server, which could be a deal breaker.

Then configure the MSTest.exe to run in the tasks list, but first you'll have to make a batch file to delete the results files from previous passes as this file's existence causes an error.

Then create a xslt to format the results and put it into the dashboard.config file.

The code project article I found has a lot more detail.

[Integrating Visual Studio Team System 2008 Unit Tests with CruiseControl.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/VSTS2008_Tests_With_CCNET.aspx)

Comment: You can run mstest without installing visual studio 2008. I've blogged about it here: http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2008/11/executing-visual-studio-unit-tests.html